# Changes not reflecting on mobile devices

Tags: magento2.3, mobile-device

Any changes which i do on my site are reflecting on desktop but not on mobile devices. why so.
The code changes are not at all reflecting on mobile devices

Answer (score 1):

Please check your theme might be there are two different theme for desktop and mobile versions.

GoTo **app/design/frontend**  and check your theme.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your var folder and run the below command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

This will clear all of your caches and it may help